# How to get file metadata from local storage in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

My app allows user to record a video, which are being saved in isolated storage i.e. `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. Another screen would show all the recorded videos. It will have a listbox with below given format.

```
Video Thumbnail | Video Name | Video Duration (hh:mm:ss) | Video Creation Date
```

I can't find any way to extract thumbnail, video duration and video creation date. I tried the below given code but it throws exception. Can anyone help me out in this?

```csharp
var LocalStorage = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync();

foreach (var file in LocalStorage)
{
    // Throws 'System.NotSupportedException' 
    var thumb = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.VideosView);

    // Throws 'System.NotImplementedException'
    var check = new List<string>();
    check.Add("System.DateCreated");
    var bprop = await (await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).RetrievePropertiesAsync(check);

    // Throws 'System.NotSupportedException' 
    var prop = await file.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the exceptions indicate, these properties are not available on the phone.
This means that it's not possible to extract a thumbnail or other metadata from the video.

Comment: Then what's the solution. How to get what I want?